# Empty ExtendedProperties in Google Contacts

Tags: c#, google-api, gdata, google-contacts-api

Some users of my application (which uses Google API .NET client) during update of Google contacts are receiving error like:
`[Line 23, Column 38, element gd:extendedProperty] exactly one of g:extendedProperty/@value, XML is required.`

This is triggered by element: `<gd:extendedProperty name="GCon" />`
which does not have value filled.  I am not updating this field, I am updating other fields (via call to Google .NET API Update call) and despite this error is thrown.  I do not see how I can overcome this.  I can find such property, but API does not give me option to set it to empty value.  I can put some dummy value:
`<gd:extendedProperty name="GCon" value="dummy"/>` but I do not want to broke some other application which sets this property.

What other solutions do I have?

Comment: You can grab the source for the Gdata library I dont think anyone is supporting it anymore you may be able to fix it yourself if it is a bug. https://github.com/google/google-gdata/issues

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug.

But regardless, if you have no interest in using extended properties, or, more importantly, making decisions about conflicts of already malformed data, you should use the `base` projection in the URL instead of `full` to avoid extended properties altogether.

Comment: Unlucky I need to add my own other extended property, so I cannot switch to `base` projection.

Comment: You can use the projection to filter a single property. e.g.:
`/m8/feeds/contacts/default/property-YourPropertyHere`